# Wordpress Update through email

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I have a blog, that is update pretty often. I like, while on the road to be able to use my blackberry or any eepc to prepare my post, review it, and send and email to somewhere that will be able to update my blog

three solution come to my mind

1. offline blog, edit and resync when return (not super good)
2. send email, update blog with blackberry
3. write text doc, send it by email and manually copy-paste in new post after return

I like not to have a list of all the possible solution, but the best working solution that you have use/try and like...

I use wp 2.6

thanks

--

**Note** just as boj note, I discover the already there feature included in wordpress... but I like my post to be in a **Drafts** state, because some photos and later editing will be done, but most of the post will already there

I have found that list. Just as [Weblog Client](http://codex.wordpress.org/Weblog_Client) said, there is a tons of software to do that, i just like THE BEST ONE !

Comment: There is a pretty good [blog post](http://www.wphub.com/tutorials/how-to-update-wordpress-via-email/) on the topic of how to configure Wordpress to do this which also talks about postie which is a nice plugin on top of the built in capability to do this in WordPress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Post to your blog using email](http://codex.wordpress.org/Blog_by_Email).

> WordPress can be configured to use e-mail to post to a blog. To enable this functionality, you need to:
>
> - Create a dedicated e-mail account to be used solely for posting to your blog,
> - Configure WordPress to access that account, and
> - Configure WordPress to publish messages from the e-mail account